# Rails + Mongoid + Devise: how to set custom user's ID on user's registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I'm using Rails + Mongoid + Devise.

I don't want to use Mongo's default IDs for **User** model (such as "524025a57c280ca442000016"). I want to use "username" instead because it is also unique.

How can I achieve that with Devise gem? When user registers his username should be written into "_id" field. So then when I call `current_user._id` - I get `"johnsmith"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple. It was required to add just one line to User model:

```
field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ username }
```